# Having trouble encoding text with a vigenere cipher in Haskell

Tags: haskell, encryption, vigenere

I'm working on a coding project where we need to write a vigenere cypher in Haskell.  I've spent hours and made little progress, but I'm stuck on one particular part.  Here is my code so far:

```
--Program: VigCipher.hs
--Author: Mouse

import Data.Char
import Text.Printf

--Changes letters to their numerical value
let2int   :: Char -> Int
let2int c = ord c - ord 'a'

--Changes numerical values to letters
int2let   :: Int -> Char
int2let n = chr (ord 'a' + n)

--Shift letter by n mod 26 places
shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift n c | isLower c = int2let ((let2int c + n) `mod` 26)
      | otherwise = c

--Encoding function
encode         :: String -> String -> [Char]
encode key msg = [shift (26 - let2int (key !! a) | a <- as) (msg !! a) | x <- zip (cycle key)msg]
```

My issue is in the Encoding function: I want the function to examine and change the char at every index of both the key and the message that's supposed to be encoded.  I'm under the impression that the what I have should work, but when I run it I get parsing errors because of the | in: (key !! a) | a <- as).  I don't know how to fix that, much less how to actually get the program examining/changing letters at each index like I want.  Could someone please help?

Comment: it might be helpful if you include the error

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
[element | bindings, guards]
```

Your syntax errors are that

- there are two `|` signs
- the first `|` occurs before the element-part has finished (count the parentheses)

So try

```
encode key msg = [shift (26 - let2int (key !! a)) (msg !! a)
                 | a <- as, x <- zip (cycle key) msg]
```

Your next error is because you haven't defined `as` anywhere. (And you don't appear to be using `x`.)

---

**Edit:** In the comments, you say you have changed your code to

```
encode key msg = [shift (26 - let2int (x)) (msg) | x <- zipWith (fst() key msg)]
```

and you say you are confused that you are getting an error message indicating that you have not given `zipWith` the three arguments it requires.

You have given `zipWith` one argument, and it is `(fst() key msg)`.

What I envisaged you changing your code to, was something like

```
encode key msg = zipWith f (cycle key) msg
  where f keyElem msgElem = shift (26 - let2int keyElem) msgElem
```

Comment: so if I wanted it to go through each index of the message and change it, should I just change as to length (msg)?

Comment: No, because `as` has to be a list. So replace it with `[0 .. length msg - 1]`. But note that using `!!` is often a bad idea (linked lists are not arrays): you could rewrite the `shift` expression in terms of `zipWith` and get rid of the `a` variable altogether.

Comment: by rewrite do you mean rewrite the shift method or rewrite where I use shift in the encoding method?

Comment: I worded it badly before, sorry. I mean to rewrite `encode` so that it uses `zipWith` and `shift` instead of using a list comprehension and `shift`.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the code to use zipWith, but it's now giving me errors because it thinks I'm using too few arguments.  This is what I've got:


encode key msg = [shift (26 - let2int (x)) (msg) |  x <- zipWith (fst() key msg)]

Yet the zipWith function should use 3 parameters just like I've passed, correct?

Comment: OH! ok, I understand--so it thought everything in the parentheses was only one argument?  And in your edited one the function f, cycle key and msg are the necessary 3 arguments?  Alright.  I'll work with this and see what I can do.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

With [parallel list comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) enabled (by sticking `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` at the top of your file, or by entering `:set -XParallelListComp` in GHCi), you can write:

```
encode key msg = [shift (26 - let2int k) m | k <- cycle key | m <- msg]
```

This will be desugared to

```
encode key msg = [shift (26 - let2int k) m | (k,m) <- zip (cycle key) msg]
```

which is the same as

```
encode key msg = zipWith (\k m -> shift (26 - let2int k) m) (cycle key) msg
```

i.e. dave4420's solution. His solution is a lot more idiomatical and does not depend on GHC extensions - so use that one by all means! Just thought I'd show a nice and compact way of writing it.

Comment: +1 for the link on parallel list comprehension, thanks I've learned something new :)